# Updating gallery when image loaded

Tags: reactjs

I am downloading image urls from firebase and then passing them to my [react-photo-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-photo-gallery) but currently they arent loading until i click on an existing image that existed locally. Im assuming this triggers the gallery to reload but i dont know how to make it do this on demand.

```
        var allPhotos = [];

  class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.getFirstImagesFromAllusers();
      this.state = { currentImage: 0 };
    }

    addImage(image) {
      newPhotos = allPhotos.push(image);
      this.setState({
        allPhotos: newPhotos,
      });
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className='app'>
          <header>
              <div className='wrapper'>
                <h1>Scott and Viki</h1>

              </div>
          </header>
          <div>
            <Gallery photos={allPhotos} onClick={this.openLightbox} />
            <Lightbox images={allPhotos}
              onClose={this.closeLightbox}
              onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
              onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
              currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
              isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    getFirstImagesFromAllusers() {
      const dataRef = firebase.database().ref('AllUsers');
      var allUsers = [];
      dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(user) {
          var images = [];
          const name = user.val().name;
          user.forEach(function(imagesSnapshot) {
            imagesSnapshot.forEach(function(imageSnapshot) {
              const count = imageSnapshot.val().count;
              const dateTime = imageSnapshot.val().dateTime;
              const isAnImage = imageSnapshot.val().isAnImage;
              const name = imageSnapshot.val().name;
              const url = imageSnapshot.val().url;
              const image = new Image(count, dateTime, isAnImage, name, url);
              images.push(image)
              allPhotos.push( { // reload/update gallery here
                src: image.url,
                width: 1,
                height: 1
              })
            });
          });
          user = new User(name, images);
          console.log(user.imageWithLowestCount());
          allUsers.push(user);
          console.log(allUsers);
        });
      })
    }
  }
```

Ideally, the gallery would reload when I call `allPhotos.push` in the for loop. I tried calling `this.addImage` in the forEach loop but get errors saying `Cannot read property 'addImage' of undefined`

Any help would be great as this is my first react app

Comment: If you can provide a JSFiddle or a pen integrated with your Firebase, then it would be easier to help.

Comment: ill give it a go, never done it before only seen them, unsure how i would connect it to firebase

Comment: looked further into it and cant add a fiddle wothout exposing my app keys and ids im afraid